# How to covert String into array in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

How to convert String into the array in React Native.
  for example:-

```
var myString = 'this, is my, string';
```

separate string with `","`
  and output must be

```
  myArray = [this, is my, string];
  on myArray[0] value is "this",
  on myArray[1] value is " is my",
  on myArray[2] value is " string"
```

Comment: `myString.split(',')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply use `string.split()` to split the string into an array using commas as delimiters.

```
var myArray = myString.split(',');
```

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help.

Comment: If you are satisfied, please mark it as the answer to you question ;)

Answer (score 6):

```js
var myString = 'this, is my, string';

console.log(myString.split(','));
```

Answer (score 2):

here is my example

```
var oldString = 'this, is my, string';
var mynewarray=oldString.split(',')
console.log("My New Array Output is",mynewarray);
```

and output like that

```
My New Array Output is [ 'this', ' is my', ' string' ]
```